# How to remove #N/A from a range object?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a function

```
Public Function dummy(x As Double, vec As Range) As Double
.
.
.
End Function
```

Sometimes the range I get to pass to `vec` contains `#N/A`. How do I remove `#N/A` from `vec` before assigning the values to an array? I am not looking to replace `#N/A` with another value though.

Comment: _I am not looking to replace #N/A with another value though._ So what _are_ you looking to do?

Comment: If I had 2 #N/As out of 10 values, then I was wondering if there was a vba function which could return the 8 value excluding #N/As. I didn't want to replace the #N/As with zero or blank. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `isna( value )` function in your VBA. I don't have Excel installed on my machine and this is not tested. But something like this should work:

```
for each cl in vec
    if WorksheetFunction.isna(cl.value) = true then
        cl.clear
    end if
next cl
```

Comment: I think the correct form should be `for each cl in vec`

Comment: Thanks, eventually I also used something similar.

Comment: How does this answer the Q when you say "I don't want to replace the #N/A's with zero or blank"?

Comment: @Chris, I had answered the question before the OP posted the comment about not wanting zeros or blanks. My proposed method can still be used to loop through the input range to create a new array or range object.

Answer (score 1):

Use an **Array** rather than a **Range.**

You can loop thru the elements of the array and remove any *#N/A* without changing the range.